# Background Images not showing in IE (all versions)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've read the other posts related to this topic but they all seem to deal with older versions of IE.  My background images on this site: https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/content/1067654511?portalId=291137&_preview=true&preview_key=6H3B1peN
show in all other browser except IE and it's not just one image in particular it's all of my bg images.  Notably, there should be background image behind the "This is where we will put the New Wellspring Pharma “you” statement..." in the banner (class: .home-banner).

Any insight here would be appreciated.  Here's my standard background image css:

```
.home-banner {
  background: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/291137/file-1090097871-png/Images_COS/home-banner_v3.png') no-repeat top left;
min-height: 340px!important;
border-bottom: 15px solid #555555;
```

}

Comment: Looks like a security issue. I was asked if I wanted to see unsecure content in IE11 Devtools. Cross-domain issue?

Comment: That was it.  I was in preview mode (not published). When I published the images showed up.  Can't explain it because I had other similar pages that weren't published but the images showed.  Anyways, thanks for taking a look.  I really appreciate it.